# Disallow SCP fallback via WinSCP .NET assembly API

Tags: sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using WinSCP .NET assembly to upload files.

I'm using SFTP and I'm unable to upload files to one of my SFTP servers. 
However, I'm able to upload to the same server when *'Allow SCP fallback'* option is unchecked.

Is there any way to set this option using the API, so I hope my file upload would work?

WinSCP version 5.5.5

Answer (score 0):

The WinSCP .NET assembly always behaves like the *"Allow SCP fallback"* is unchecked. You cannot even turn the option on.

So your problem must be different.

---

*Append session logs both from .NET assembly and GUI to get better answer.*